# Get dynamic text from readonly textbox using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, textbox, selenium-webdriver

I have a text box which contains hours represented from 1 to 24. Hours are incremented and decremented when we click on Up Arrow and Down Arrows(Hyperlinka) above and below the textboxes.

Here is the code for my textbox.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="hours" ng-change="updateHours()" 
class="form-control text-center ng-pristine ng-valid" 
ng-mousewheel="incrementHours()" ng-readonly="readonlyInput" 
maxlength="2" readonly="readonly">
```

I have tried the below code. But no luck.

```
findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("Hours"))).getAttribute("ng-change");
```

Can any one help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the input and get the value of `value` attribute:

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//input[@ng-model="hours"]'));
System.out.println(input.getAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: I am getting this exception. (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element

Comment: @Vikram ok, what about `WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("Hours")));`?

Comment: @Vikram do you have any `iframe` or `frame` tags on the page? Thanks.

Comment: Give me 2 mins I am keeping a delay and will check. Thanks